# Scala parsing Weird XML

Tags: xml, scala

Given the following XML

```
<a>
   <b>1111
      <c>2222</c>
   </b>
</a>
```

does anybody know the best way to extract the value `"1111"` at the beginning of the `<b>` tag?

I have tried `(xml \ "b").mkstring.split("\n")(0)` and it works, but I believe there may be a better way to do that.

Unfortunately I have no control over the document structure.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use pattern matching for this:

```
val xml = <a><b>1111<c>2222</c></b></a>

val result = xml match {
  case <a><b>{n}<c>{_}</c></b></a> => Some(n.text)
  case _ => None
}

println(result) // 1111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regular Expression that can extract the result. Something like `<b>(\d+)`. Assuming the 'XML' will always be in this format.

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely assume that there is *always* a `b` element, you only want the one, and it *always* contains a text element at the beginning, then you can do this:

```
val b = (xml \ "b").head

b.child.head.text
res0: String = 1111
```